# Excel Randomize Decimal Number

Tags: excel, random

I found a very nice function in MS Excel 2007 which is `RANDBETWEEN(bottom, top)`. The problem with this is that it randomize whole number only. Using this formula:

```
=RANDBETWEEN(7.0, 9.9)
```

yields

```
8.0
9.0
7.0
7.0
etc...
```

How can I modify it so that it will also produce decimal numbers like below

```
7.5
7.2
9.4
9.5
7.1
8.5
etc...
```

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Use `randbetween(70,99)` and divide the result by 10.

Answer (score 3):

Refer this  [http://ms-office.wonderhowto.com/how-to/generate-random-numbers-with-decimals-excel-338595/](http://link)

Random decimal number between 30-40

```
=rand()*10+30
```

Random decimal number between 0-100

```
=rand()*100+0
```

Answer (score 2):

Since `RANDBETWEEN()` used to be available exclusively in the Analysis ToolPak (and produced a #NAME? error [when the ToolPak was not installed](http://office.microsoft.com/en-001/excel-help/randbetween-HP005209230.aspx)), you might be better off using `RAND()` for backwards compatibility, multiplying and adding to shift the range and rounding to one decimal place:

```
=ROUNDUP(7 + RAND() * (9.9 - 7 - 0.1), 1)    ' Excludes 7.0 and 9.9
=ROUNDUP(7 + RAND() * (9.9 - 7), 1)          ' Excludes 7.0, includes 9.9    
=ROUNDDOWN(7 + RAND() * (9.9 - 7), 1)        ' Includes 7.0, excludes 9.9
=ROUNDDOWN(7 + RAND() * (9.9 - 7 + 0.1), 1)  ' Includes 7.0 and 9.9
```

But the `RANDBETWEEN()` issue is just a backwards compatibility issue now, so if you're sure your spreadsheet will only be used in Excel 2007 and up, you'll be fine with either approach.